# Como altero o retorno de um método (WebMethod) em ASMX?

Tags: c#, asmx

Desenvolvi um ASMX com um método, e ao executar o código no retorno desse método, o mesmo monta um XML a partir de uma determinada classe definida por um Schema XSD, que porem vem uma TAG com sufixo result,  como posso alterar isso ?

```
[WebMethod]
public UpsertContasResponse upsertContas(upsertContas.req req)
{
   ---- codigos  -----
   var cliRetorno = new UpsertContasResponse(){
            codigo = req.Codigo,
            descricao = (erro == null ? null : erro),
            status = "OK",
            OrgBukrs = "XXXX"
    };
           
    return cliRetorno;
 }
```

XML que é gerado no retorno :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <upsertContasResponse>
         <upsertContasResult>
            <codigo>0000000281</codigo>
            <descricao/>
            <status>OK</status>
            <OrgBukrs>XXXX</OrgBukrs>
         </upsertContasResult>
      </upsertContasResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

quero alterar o nome dessa tag " "  que não defino em local algum, como faço ??

Comment: Qual tag " "? onde você está vendo isso?

Comment: problema foi solucionado. na verdade alterei o metodo do asmx que faz o processo adicionando os parametros abaixo acima do Metodo.           

[SoapDocumentMethod(ResponseElementName = "UpsertContasReponse")]
[return: XmlElement("result")]

Isso fez com que ele me gerasse o retorno no formato esperado de XML.